# How to send an email message in a specific conversation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The use case is programmatically sending a follow-up email to a recipient in the same conversation / thread using the Microsoft Graph API instead of creating a new email in a new conversation (similar to the behavior when "replying" to a message you've already sent to a recipient in Outlook).

My understanding is that conversations and threads are reflected via the `conversationId` property

I see that there is [a Create Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) method, but specifying a specific conversation id does not seem to be reflected in the created object.

Unsurprisingly, conversation id also does not seem to a writable field defined by [the Update Message method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs).

Using [the Create Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) or [Create Reply All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreplyall?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) method to reply to the original message you sent returns a `400` response code (which is understandable) with an error code of `ErrorInvalidReferenceItem` and the error message `The reference item does not support the requested operation.`.

Finally, defining an explicit `In-Reply-To` Header is prohibited when creating an email message.

Answer (score 1):

The Create Reply All API method works as expected - I was just referencing a draft message id when trying to reply, and as one would expect, that request errors.

Comment: I am getting this error `{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidReferenceItem","message":"The reference item does not support the requested operation."}}` I am using original message reposnse "id" as message id
Where am I doing wrong?